# Parse a string stored in a member variable

Tags: autohotkey

I have a simple class that stores a string in a member variable and has a method for doing something with that string. The method should iterate the string and do something with each character.

Here is my code:

```
class ParseString
{
    __New(Str)
    {
        this.Str := Str
    }

    DoSomething()
    {
        ; The error happens on this line
        Loop, Parse, %this.Str%
        {
            ; Do something with A_LoopField
        }
}
```

The expected behavior was for the line that throws an error to actually loop over the characters on the string, but I get an error: "The following variable name contains an illegal character this.str".

I have already tried not dereferencing the variable, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use legacy syntax for the `Loop, Parse` command since it takes a variable as input.
Here is the full syntax for the command:

```
Loop, Parse, InputVar [, Delimiters, OmitChars]
```

To use the command, you don't need to use the percent sign around the name, otherwise it will be a dynamic variable and will parse the variable named with the content of `InputVar`.

Therefore, to parse the variable `this.Str` you will need to write the command like so:

```
Loop, Parse, this.Str
    {
        ; Do something with A_LoopField
    }
```

Comment: That's a bit odd. I tried that and got the same error. I'm running ahk 1.1.30.01